# Redirecting to non-angular url within angular web-app

Tags: javascript, authentication, angularjs, laravel, laravel-4

Currently we are developing a angular web-app with Laravel view as initial entry point. User authentication is done in Laravel side, upon the successful authentication Angular.js takes charge.

We fetch the data through a API based on aforementioned Laravel backend. Since sometimes session cookie expires midway through the lifetime of the app, we are making sure that user is  authenticated user by checking for 401 status using `httpInterceptor`. Upon the detection of `401` status, I want to redirect to `appPath/auth/login` which is a route handled by Laravel.

I know we can achieve this by injecting `$window` to the `httpInterceptor` and setting `$window.location.href` to `appPath/auth/login`. But it seems pretty un-angular way of doing it.

Are there any elegant angular way to perform above mentioned task?

Comment: Not sure, but $location.path("/appPath/auth/login"), should work. See docs here. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$location

Regards

Comment: @Guillermo I checked, but it didn't work. The problem is `auth/login` is not a route managed by angular. Where routes managed by angular take `appPath/#/route1` shape this path takes `appPath/auth/login`.

Comment: Using `$location.url()` instead, does it work?

Comment: You have to do it with $window because you want to get out of the Angular app .. And this app is attached to $window

Comment: $location.url() did not work either. Seems like using $window is the only way.

Comment: Using $window seems like the Angular way to me. I cannot think of anything built in to Angular that would be any more elegant.